# Пустая форма (PHP, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Смотрю по видеоурокам как сделать форму. Собственно вот она:

```
<form action="{{ route('contact-form') }}" method="post">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Send Message">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </form>
```

А вот файл web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

---> Немного сократил тут код, чтобы было легче прочитать

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
});

Route::post('/contact/submit', 'ContactController@submit')->name('contact-form');
```

Сам ContactController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $req) {
        dd($req);
    }
}
```

И выдает только токен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не присылает остальные input (name, email, phone, message)
Только осваиваю Laravel, подскажите что делать, пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможно вам следует замазать токен на скрине

Comment: Да это тестовый, на локалке запущен, но спасибо, учту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас input-ы **не идентифицированы** - добавьте аттрибут **name** в каждый input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name='name'>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name='email'>
```

и т.д.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: И МНЕ ПОМОГ. СПАСИБО

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, обработчик формы идентифицирует поля формы по значению атрибута name, а не id (это не особенность Laravel, так работают все HTML-формы). У Вас этого атрибута нет. Может быть, дело в этом.

Comment: Большое спасибо